# How to use POST method to upload file in google-api-java-client?

Tags: android, google-api-java-client

google-api-java-client is a good web service api client on Android, however I mean a problem and spend lots of time on it.

I want to upload a file via POST method, so I study the google-drive API source code, but it uses the media uploader to upload file to google drive.

so how to upload a file via POST method in google-api-java-client?

for example Imgur upload API method has two require parameter.

suppose a upload file API written in google-api-java-client like this, but i have no idea how should I fill in the 'image' field which marked ???

```
public class ImgurImage extends GenericJson {
  @com.google.api.client.util.Key("key")
  private String mKey;

  @com.google.api.client.util.Key("image")
  private ??? mImage
}

public class Upload extends JsonHttpRequest {
  private static final String REST_PATH = "/2/upload.json"

  private Upload(ImgurImage content) {
    super(ImgurClient.this, HttpMethod.POST, REST_PATH, content);
  }

  public void execute() throws IOException {
    executeUnparsed();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend taking a look at our Drive API sample at http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/drive-cmdline-sample/instructions.html

Here's a code snippet:

```
  private static final java.io.File UPLOAD_FILE = new java.io.File(UPLOAD_FILE_PATH);

  /** Uploads a file using either resumable or direct media upload. */
  private static File uploadFile(boolean useDirectUpload) throws IOException {
    File fileMetadata = new File();
    fileMetadata.setTitle(UPLOAD_FILE.getName());
    InputStreamContent mediaContent = new InputStreamContent("image/jpeg", new BufferedInputStream(
        new FileInputStream(UPLOAD_FILE)));
    mediaContent.setLength(UPLOAD_FILE.length());
    Drive.Files.Insert insert = drive.files().insert(fileMetadata, mediaContent);
    MediaHttpUploader uploader = insert.getMediaHttpUploader();
    uploader.setDirectUploadEnabled(useDirectUpload);
    uploader.setProgressListener(new FileUploadProgressListener());
    return insert.execute();
  }
```

Comment: Your link is dead, it'd be nice if you could fix that

Answer (score 0):

I use httpClient and I use FileBody to send a file to a server, as part of a MultiPartEntity. This works for Picasa, Flickr, etc.

Comment: even successful for uplaoding mp4 / 3gp  ?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you adopted a sample that was uploading text (json in content, json in the REST URL endpoint) and used it to attempt image upload ( upload(ImgurImage)  ).

So, look at the source for the 'GenericJson.upload(ImgurImage)'...

See what this method does when it sets the 'content' field prior to calling 'exec' on the POST.

Understand that these frameworks will allow either strings and text in content or allow bitmaps ( bytes ) for images and audio type uploads.

Look for a handler that sets the 'content' and understand how it handles both bytes and strings for the json sample.

that should help you use the framework you have chosen.